# Is there a way to find the running timers in java?

Tags: java, android, timer

Is there a method to find out how many timers are running in Java? Something like an *ActivityManager* for *Activities* in Android ?

I noticed that timers can be created with a given name. How can I refer to a timer by it's name?

> public Timer (String name, boolean isDaemon) Added in API level 1
>
> Creates a new named Timer which may be specified to be run as a daemon
>   thread. Throws NullPointerException   if name == null

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code you will see all active threads

```
    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
        System.out.println(t.getName());
    }
```

those with Timer-x names are Timers

Comment: Yes. But how can I stop that timer when I find it by name ? I tried to convert the _thread_ to a _Timer_, but it isn't allowed.

Comment: I tried the .interrupt() method from Threads, but for some reason it doesn't do anything.